# Is it possible to use CSS with SharePoint Online?

Tags: css, sharepoint-online

According to [the site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/customize-a-sharepoint-page-by-using-remote-provisioning-and-css), it cannot, but I'm wondering if there is some alternative to create nice looking webpages on SharePoint online.

Answer (score 0):

You may inject styles into page header by creating an application customizer. See following links for details:

- https://tahoeninjas.blog/2018/05/08/inject-custom-css-on-sharepoint-modern-pages-using-spfx-extensions/
- https://tahoeninjas.blog/2018/10/29/update-inject-custom-css-on-sharepoint-modern-pages-using-spfx-application-extensions/

Answer (score 0):

You could use the modern script editor web part to insert css in your page by installing the react-script-editor framework: https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-script-editor